# Implementando view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, view, procedure

Exibir extrato de uma determinada conta com os respectivos movimentos de um
período de quinze dias anteriores à data de solicitação com os seguintes dados:

- Agência;
- Número da conta;
- Nome do titular da conta;
- Identificação do titular da conta (CPF ou CNPJ);
- Tipo da conta;
- Situação da conta;
- Tipo de movimento;
- Data do movimento;
- Valor do movimento;
- Saldo da conta.

Eu implementei essa view:

```sql
create view v_extrato_conta as
select c.agencia,
       c.numero_conta, 
       t.nome,
       t.CPF_CNPJ, 
       c.tipo,
       c.estado_conta,
       m.operacao,
       m.data_movimento,
       m.valor,
       c.saldo 
from conta c 
inner join correntista t 
on c.idconta = t.idcorrentista
inner join movimento m
on c.idconta = m.idmovimento;
```

e criei essa procedure para chamar essa view:

```sql
delimiter #
create procedure exibi_extrato_conta(data_solicitacao date)
begin 
    select * from v_extrato_conta where data_solicitacao < 15;
end
#
```

mas eu não consigo ter retorno de nenhum dado, se eu retirar a condição de `data_solicitacao < 15` e passar qualquer data de solicitação e chamar a procedure, ela me trás os dados. Como eu poderia fazer essa query decrementando 15 dias da `data_solicitacao` ? Espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: Se `data_solicitacao` é um parâmetro de sua procedure qual o sentido de você utilizar tal parâmetro em sua query comparando com uma constante? Será que você não deveria verificar se `data_movimento` está no período de 15 dias anteriores à  `data_solicitacao`?

Answer (score 0):

Caso o tipo de dado da coluna `data_solicitacao` seja date é necessário fazer o cast para poder comparar os valores de maneira correta.

Em sua query você tem uma data_solicitação (tipo date) e está tentando fazer uma comparação com o tipo inteiro. Por isso o problema em sua query.

No caso de datas você deve utilizar o operador `interval` do `mysql`, porém cada sistema de banco de dados possui suas funções de comparação de datas.
 Supondo que queremos o intervalo entre a data de hoje e quize dias atrás, devemos fazer:

```
delimiter #
create procedure exibi_extrato_conta(data_solicitacao date)
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM v_extrato_conta WHERE data_solicitacao BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 15 DAY) AND NOW();
END
#
```

Em meu exemplo utilizei o operador `between`, mas pode ser utilizando também os operadores maior igual da maneira que está fazendo.

```
 delimiter #
    create procedure exibi_extrato_conta(data_solicitacao date)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM v_extrato_conta WHERE data_solicitacao <= NOW() AND 
        data_solicitacao >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 15 DAY);
    END
    #
```

Segue a documentação para [date add mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)